# HTML not find JS and CSS files in WebBrowserControl in VB.NET

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a desktop application with an **installer**, so the file paths are **dynamic**, I use a **webBrowser** in the application to simulate a protocol with HTML, CSS and JS files to be lighter than generating by WinForms. The point is that HTML is not able to reach the folder inside the solution that contains the CSS and JS files, follow the example below:

[Project and Folder in solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNndl.png)

Here the folder structure of ProtocoloHTML

[Folder Estructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOY30.png)

[The code in HTML file for find the other files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN3aY.png)

[Find the HTML file by VB.NET to webBrowser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVH0m.png)

Comment: Are the files copied to the project's `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` folder when you compile? If not, select each file in the `Solution Explorer` and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`. You then have to make sure that you include this folder and its contents wherever you move your .exe-file.

Comment: I did what you suggested, the folder was generated in the release and in the debug which was a good evolution, I redirected the opening path of the webbrowser html file to the executable release but the html continues without loading the CSS and JS files.

Comment: Please show me your updated code and the contents of your new directory.